# How to convert unsigned short 7273 to ascii HI

Tags: c

This code below prints two characters HI using i=72 and j=73.
Is there a similar method to print HI when k=7273?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    
      unsigned short i = 72;
      unsigned short j = 73;
      unsigned short k = 7273;

      printf("%c%c",(char)i, (char)j);

      return 0;
   }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8cGMMM156

Comment: Do some math first.

Comment: I'm not sure you meant to use decimal.  It's more usual to do this sort of thing in hexadecimal (base 16), where you'd have `i = 0x48`, `j = 0x49`, and `k = 0x4849`.

Comment: Hexadecimal would also let you handle lower case letters (which require 3 digits in decimal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
printf ("%c%c", k / 100, k % 100);
```

(you don't need any casts).

Comment: D'Oh! That was embarrassing. I was thinking arrays, itoa, ntohs, ascii, +"0" but not the simple maths divison and remainder.